# STM32G474 not erasing flash by page?

Tags: stm32, c, flash

I am writing to the flash memory of an STM32G474RE using the HAL libraries.

Here is the section of code I've been using:

```
   /* Unlock the Flash to enable the flash control register access *************/
   HAL_FLASH_Unlock();

   /* Clear OPTVERR bit set on virgin samples */
   __HAL_FLASH_CLEAR_FLAG(FLASH_FLAG_OPTVERR);

   EraseInitStruct.TypeErase    = FLASH_TYPEERASE_PAGES;
   EraseInitStruct.Page         = ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_255;
   EraseInitStruct.NbPages      = 1;
   EraseInitStruct.Banks        = 2;

   HAL_FLASHEx_Erase(&EraseInitStruct, &PAGEError);

   HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_DOUBLEWORD, ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_255, 0);

   HAL_FLASHEx_Erase(&EraseInitStruct, &PAGEError);

   HAL_FLASH_Lock();
```

The first program function works, if I erase all flash on debugging. However the following erase function does not work. I can monitor the values in the flash locations using STM32CubeIDE.

When I change

```
   EraseInitStruct.TypeErase    = FLASH_TYPEERASE_MASSERASE;
   EraseInitStruct.Page         = ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_255;
```

The erase function will start to work. But of course the whole bank gets erased. Which is not what I want.

What I don't understand is if I change

```
   EraseInitStruct.TypeErase    = FLASH_TYPEERASE_PAGES;
   EraseInitStruct.Page         = ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_128;
```

Only page 128 gets erased?

Can anyone explain why I can page erase page 128 but not 255? They're the same bank, the program memory is in a different bank, I can erase other pages in this bank? The datasheet also specifies that I can do pages erases?

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the issue.

```c
 EraseInitStruct.Page
```

is supposed to be the page number of the bank (0-127). ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_XXX is the memory address of the start of the page.